# how readUTF() method of DataInputStream finish form Keyboard?

Tags: java, io, datainputstream

This is my test:

```
    DataInputStream dis=new DataInputStream(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter your name: ");
    String name=dis.readUTF();
    System.out.println("Ten vua nhap: "+name);// want to print
```

After input some text from the keyboard, i want to finish and print the text, but the programm still not finish.. how can i deal with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can you the Scanner class easily

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter your name: ");
    String name= input.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Ten vua nhap: "+name);// want to print
```

Answer (score 1):

> how readUTF() method of DataInputStream finish form Keyboard?

You can't use `readUTF()` from a keyboard. You can only use it when the data source is using `writeUTF().` See the Javadoc. They share a unique data format that nothing else I am aware of produces.

Use `BufferedReader.readLine(),` and test for `null`, which you will get when ctrl/d is entered at the console (ctrl/z for Unix, Linux, AIX, Solaris, HP-UX, ...).